# How do I convert a human readable time duration "23m 10.3s" to seconds in PHP?

Tags: php, time, php-carbon, duration

I have time duration strings "23m 10.3s", how do I convert that to seconds? Does Carbon have a method for doing this? I looked at the docs and nothing stood out.

Comment: Please provide some code what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Carbon has a short way to parse strings like that:

```
$interval = \Carbon\CarbonInterval::fromString("23m 10.3s");

echo $interval->totalSeconds;
```

Output: 1390.3

Comment: Awesome thanks! It seem you got in there before someone closed my question because it didn't have a code example....